# Maximum Sum Subarray O(n) not Kadane's

Tags: java, algorithm, arrays, kadanes-algorithm

I'm reading Cormen's "Introduction to Algorithms".

For the linear algorithm for Max Sum Subarray problem I came up with my own solution. Didn't check existing one (Kadena's) before implementing.

Now I'm testing it with different test scenarios and always have better results than Kadena's. I don't believe in such a luck, but can't find what have I missed. Could you take a look whether it is a working solution?

```java
public void findMaxSubarray(Number[] numbers) {
    int maxSum = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int left = 0;
    int right = numbers.length - 1;

    int i = 0;
    int j = i + 1;
    int sum = numbers[i].intValue();

    while (i < numbers.length) {
        if (maxSum < sum) {
            maxSum = sum;
            left = i;
            right = j - 1;
        }
        if (j >= numbers.length)
            return;
        sum = sum + numbers[j].intValue();
        if (sum <= 0) {
            // ignoring "first" negative numbers. shift i to first non-negative
            while (numbers[j].intValue() <= 0) {
                if (maxSum < numbers[j].intValue()) {
                    maxSum = numbers[j].intValue();
                    left = j;
                    right = j;
                }
                if (++j >= numbers.length)
                    return;
            }
            i = ++j;
            sum = 0;
        }
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Max subarray is %d, [%d; %d]", maxSum, left, right));
}
```

**Update**
The idea of code is to keep in track only one subarray, and adding to its' tail numbers, when numbers are that low that sum becomes negative - set beginning of array after the tail.
Additionally negative items in the beginning are being ignored. head of subarray is just shifted forward. 
Everytime sum appears to be maximum - maxSum and limits are updated.

```
shift i() --to first non negative number
from j = i+1 up to N.length
  sum + N[j]
  if sum <= 0
    i = j+1
    if N[i] < 0
      shift i()
    sum = 0
```

Comment: It will be better if you explain your algorithm with the help of pseudo-code.

Comment: What do you mean "better results than Kadane's"?  Kadane's algorithm returns an optimal solution -- it sounds like you have a bug.

Comment: that's what I'm saying. Though it's not better that much. My algorithm doeant calculate sum all the time. when there are lot's of negative numbers - it just shifts start of the subarray. I'll update post with pseudo code in a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your algorithm is basically sound, but it has two bugs that I can see:

1. On the input `1 -2 10 3`, it will skip over the 10 and output 3.  I think you can fix this by changing `i = ++j;` to `i = j;`.
2. In 2 different places you `return` if `j` goes past the end, which will cause no output to be produced at all!  (This will happen if, e.g., a long list of negative numbers appears at the end of the list.)

Also I don't expect it to be faster (or slower, for that matter) than Kadane's.  Summing two numbers is a fast operation, as fast as copying one variable to another, which is what you are doing when you shift the start of the subarray.